# RDP client error - An authentication error has occured (0x609)

Tags: rdp, ntlm, credssp

I have a computer named ws24 (192.168.1.168) and another named srvPPassTest2.

I have written a program running on ws24 that is an "RDP proxy". It accepts connections from RDP clients on port 7070 (configurable) and forwards them to srvPPassTest2. I do the following to configure the computers to use the proxy:

- I create a certificate for the Proxy with the following command:
  `./makecert -n "CN=ws24.pleasant.local" -pe -ss Root -sr localMachine -sky exchange -m 120 -r -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1`

  - Then I export it with private key to create a .pfx that the Proxy will use.
  - I also export it without the private key and import that into srvPPassTest2's Certificates (Local Computer) - Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificate folder.
- I run
  `Enable-WSManCredSSP -role client -DelegateComputer srvPPassTest2
  Enable-WSManCredSSP -role client -DelegateComputer ws24
  Enable-WSManCredSSP -role client -DelegateComputer 192.168.1.168`
  on ws24. I'm sure they're not all necessary but it's not working yet so I'm trying everything.
- On ws24 I make the following registry changes:

  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Security Packages - add tspkg
  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders - add credssp.dll
- I run `Enable-WSManCredSSP -role Server` on srvPPassTest2.

*If you get any errors on the WSManCredSSP calls, try calling Enable-PSRemoting first.*

---

Here's what happens when I run the rdp proxy and use the RDP client to connect to it:

- On ws24, I use the RDP client to connect to 192.168.1.168:7070. The use of an ip address instead of a name prevents the client from responding that you can't connect to yourself.
- The proxy receives and modifies (if necessary) the ConnectionRequestPDU message of the RDP Protocol to ensure the SupportedProtocol flags are set to ProtocolHybrid & ProtocolSSL. This will ensure the use of CredSSP. That is forwarded to srvPPassTest2.
- The proxy mitm's the TLS handshake.
- The proxy receives the clients NTLMNegotiate message, takes some information from it and creates a new one to forward to the target srvPPassTest2.
- Likewise with the NTLMChallenge and NTLMAuthentication.

  - The RDP client and server are continuing fine at this point. They don't return errors or exhibit strange behavior.
- The machines exchange certificate public keys, encrypted with the key from the NTLM exchange.
- The client sends a TSRequest with a TSCredential. The proxy receives it, verifies information and constructs one with different credentials to send to srvPPassTest2.
- Forward message from client, length 462
- Forward message from srvppasstest2, length 108
- Forward message from client, length 12

Then I get an error popup from the rdp client:

> An authentication error has occured (Code: 0x609)
>   Remote computer: 192.1.168.1.168

---

The only relevant result when I look up error 0x609 is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dc4acf8e-da48-4253-a719-b378ed3a35ee/rdp-authentication-error-code-0x609?forum=winserverTS) and I've followed those steps. One important thing to note: I had this proxy working 3 months ago. Then srvPPassTest2 was reverted to a previous state and now the proxy doesn't work. I can't revert srvPPassTest2 to the state when it was working, that vm wasn't mine and the snapshot wasn't saved by IT >:(

Where does one find information about code 0x609?

What other possible settings, on ws24, or srvPPassTest2 am I missing? I think the certificate should probably be in an additional folder on srvPPassTest2, but I don't know which.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot? The NTLM and TSCredential exchanges are all working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in this step:

> - The proxy receives and modifies (if necessary) the ConnectionRequestPDU message of the RDP Protocol to ensure the SupportedProtocol flags are set to ProtocolHybrid & ProtocolSSL. This will ensure the use of CredSSP. That is forwarded to srvPPassTest2.

As it turns out, I also had to set the ProtocolHybridEx flag in the ConnectionRequestPDU. I'm guessing this is because the forwarded messages, the ones after the TSCredential, care about this flag.

That being the case, I've decided to just forward the flags used by the client, instead of building them myself. If the ProtocolHybrid flag isn't set, I'll error out gently since we require Network Level Authentication (NLA) be used.